# Toogle single radiobutton (on and off) in bokeh radiobutton group

Tags: bokeh, bokehjs

I am using bokeh single radio button with single title . Initially it is inactive and when i click on radio button it changed to active but if I click again in active it is not changing to inactive state.

How i need to acheive this functionality??

Answer (score 0):

Whether it's `RadioGroup` or `RadioButtonGroup`, neither of those two widgets is meant for a single element usage. Per design they are meant to be used as a group of elements. I advice you to use `Toggle` for your application. Other alternatives are `CheckboxButtonGroup` and `CheckboxGroup`. See [Bokeh documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html#checkbox-group) for specific examples.